# Ruby 二次元配列のまとめ方について教えてください。

Tags: ruby

配列の`[0]`には人名を、配列の`[1]`にはスコアが入っている二次元配列をまとめる方法を教えてください。

---

```
score = [["taro",10],["taro", 70], ["taro", 170], ["jiro", 90], ["jiro", 55]]
```

求める出力

```
taro => 250
jiro => 145
```

Comment: `inject()` を使って `score.group_by{|s| s[0]}.inject({}){|h, (k, v)| h[k] = v.sum{|i| i[1]};h}`

Answer (score 2):

こういうのって、大喜利かコードゴルフ大会になるからあまり多くのパターンを出し過ぎるのもよくないんですが、私好みのコードの例がなかったので、参戦します。

```
score.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |a| a.sum(&:last) }
```

[`Hash#transform_value`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Hash/i/transform_values.html)と[`Array#sum`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Array/i/sum.html)は2.4.0からですので注意してください。`&:first`と言う表現は`:first`が`to_proc`で`Proc`になってブロックとして渡されるというものです。ブロックだらけになるのをある程度は防いでくれます。

Answer (score 1):

```
score.group_by { |name, _| name }
     .map do |name, entries|
       [name, entries.map { |_, value| value }.sum]
     end.to_h
```

Enumerable クラスの、 `group_by`, `sum`, `map`, `to_h` を利用すると実現できます。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 0):

配列を舐めて各キーごとにハッシュに突っ込む感じで作ってみました。

```
score_map = Hash.new()
score.each{|pair|
    score_map.has_key?(pair[0])?score_map[pair[0]]+=pair[1]:score_map[pair[0]]=pair[1]
}

# => {"taro"=>250, "jiro"=>145}
```

もっとスマートなやり方があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

```
score = [["taro", 10], ["taro", 70], ["taro", 170], ["jiro", 90], ["jiro", 55]]
result = score.group_by do |s|
  s[0]
end.map do |k, v|
  { k => v.sum{ |num| num[1] } }
end
puts result

#=> [{"taro"=>250}, {"jiro"=>145}]
```

こんなのとか？

Answer (score 0):

```
score = [["taro",10],["taro", 70], ["taro", 170], ["jiro", 90], ["jiro", 55]]

hash = {}
score.each do |a|
  if hash[a[0]]
    hash[a[0]] = hash[a[0]] + a[1]
  else
    hash[a[0]] = a[1]
  end
end

pp hash
```